# What are standard project README and CHANGELOG variants?

Tags: npm, release, changelog, readme

[npm's developer documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package), describes README and CHANGELOG as having variants, without describing what they may be.

> README (and its variants)
>
> CHANGELOG (and its variants)

Is there a standard set of variants? If so, where would those standards be published?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variants are clarified in the [documentation on package.json#files field](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files).

Changelog can be named `CHANGES`, `CHANGELOG` or `HISTORY` with any case and extension. `README` file has the same naming flexibility.